# Suggestions of excellent examples of real C/C++ code

Tags: c++, c

I'd like to study some good C/C++ code. The code should:

1. be good in style and structure, presenting best practices
2. be a real life program (not an example or toy)
3. not too big so it doesn't takes ages to analyse it
4. Windows and/or Unix

I know there are 1000s of open source projects out there. But I'd like to hear your suggestions.

I am Java programmer and I am curious how good project in c/c++ is structured (files), granularity of classes/functions/files, documentation/comments, build tools etc.

Multiple suggestions are welcomed e.g. this is good windows example, that is good pure C etc.

Comment: This should be Community Wiki.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would specifically mention [memcached.](http://www.danga.com/memcached/) It's a great example of fairly short, readable code with a clear purpose.

Second, I would recommend the [Apache web server](http://httpd.apache.org/). It's a fantastically well-run open source project that you'll learn a lot from, both about the language, as well as general design practices and networking/threading.

Answer (score 5):

I'd vote for nginx: http://sysoev.ru/en/ as an example of a very good C programming style

Answer (score 4):

[Samba](http://www.samba.org): a large, cross-platform (POSIX-based), pure C, very popular network server.

Samba has good [developer documentation](http://www.samba.org/samba/devel/), and the code base itself is *very* well organized; I've had no problems diving into just about any location within the code to answer a question I had about its inner workings or to track down a bug.

Answer (score 3):

I find the implementation of Lua is quite nice C source.   But languages are a bit odd as an example project.

Comment: Many historical source kits (including the current 5.1.4) are at http://www.lua.org/ftp/ and there is a web interface to the current source kit at http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/

Answer (score 3):

Diomidis Spinellis has some suggestions in his book, "Code Reading: The Open Source Perspective", Addison Wesley, 2003. ISBN 0-201-79940-5.

Perhaps the book could be useful to you.

URL http://www.spinellis.gr/codereading/

Answer (score 3):

[Google's Chromium](http://dev.chromium.org/) is pretty huge, but you don't have to analyze it all to appreciate its clean, peer-reviewed structure.
Also, it's a good example of nicely done developer environment deployment.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I can only mark one answer as 'accepted', nevertheless your suggestion is the 3rd project I am going to look into.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [main file](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.sbin/relayd/relayd.c?rev=1.83;content-type=text%2Fplain) for [relayd](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.sbin/relayd/), which is a daemon that handles load balancing and failover. It's nicely written, full featured, clean C code. It's big enough that you get a feel for a "real world" program, but not so big that you can't get your head around it with some work. Great for secure, well written networking code, daemons, etc.

Modesty aside, there's also a little [tiling window manager](http://www.peereboom.us/scrotwm/scrotwm.c) for X that I've helped with. It's quite small but it's a real wm, and the other coders on it have high standards (and hold me to them!)... Nice for learning basic X stuff.

Answer (score 1):

[K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_(book)) has many good examples of real programs.  For instance, on page 115 of the Second Edition there are two simple implementations of the `echo` command.  From there, it might be interesting to see how the command was implemented over time.  For instance, there is a version in the [GNU coreutils](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/echo.c) source.  A version derived from [BSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD) can be found in [BusyBox](http://sources.busybox.net/index.py/trunk/busybox/coreutils/echo.c) source.

It might be interesting to see how the newer versions compare to the textbook examples.  Why are the programs that are used in real life longer?  How much of the code is related to new features and how much is related to dealing with edge cases?  How would you write the same code in Java?

Answer (score 0):

As for C++ I would recommend you the [Qt library sources](http://www.qtsoftware.com/downloads) and [KDE's source code](http://www.kde.org/) and its programs.

It's beautifully written code and the way that you should program in C++.

Answer (score 0):

More C++ suggestions in: [Examples of “modern c++” in action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534311/examples-of-modern-c-in-action)